# Visual Studio Code SQL Syntax Highlighting in .py Files

Tags: python, sql, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am switching over from atom to VSCode and finding it to be a way better experience for (mostly) python.

One thing I can't seem to work out is that the python syntax highlighting on atom recognised SQL in strings and highlighted it.

[image: VSCode] [image: Atom]

I can't seem to find an extension for VSCode to do the same thing.

Does one exist or is there a way to get this highlighting in VSCode?

Comment: You would need to request that MagicPython add support for it as they provide the syntax highlighting for VS Code.

Comment: I end up with an extension called [python-string-sql](https://github.com/ptweir/python-string-sql)

Answer (score 12):

The best solution I found so far is this extension: https://github.com/ptweir/python-string-sql

It highlights multi quoted strings that start with `--sql` and end with `;`, such as this one:

```py
query = f"""--sql
SELECT * FROM mytable;
"""
```

Comment: I try to use with pydal but it breaks the query.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem possible yet. But vote here:
https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/issues/27

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to @Rotareti's suggested extension, I am working on my own twist of it, that fits my personal needs.
It activates sql highlighting when sees one of the three starting keywords in multiline string (multiline starting with `"""` or `f"""`). Highlighting is deactivated when multiline string ends.
Only real limitation is that the keyword has to be in first line of string.

I have not published my package yet, but you can find it here:
https://github.com/uogiukas/python-string-sql

Having `--sql` to start highlight just does not fit me since I have to go through a lot of other peoples' or my own old code where no such comment exists.

Answer (score 2):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iuyoy.highlight-string-code

Works as expected with no --sql prefix

Comment: Works very well! Just make sure that your stings doesn't start with whitespaces etc.